# Polylang WP plugin add United Arab Emirates language

Tags: wordpress, arabic, arabic-support

I use Polylang Wordpress plugin and need to add United Arab Emirates language to site.. in drop down there is no options to chose corresponding language ( United Arab Emirates ) to Arabic.. but here https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/polylang/trunk/settings/flags.php I can see

```
'ae' => __( 'United Arab Emirates', 'polylang' ),
```

So, I try to add language with this settings: ( Locale: ar_AE, Code: ae ), but there is no flag

[image: http://prntscr.com/9obcra]

and also I get message to need download wordpress files because translate files is not downloaded

Is there some options or alternative to get this work correctly.. maybe to add Arabic default language and just change custom flag, because its look like plugin not work with United Arab Emirates Localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to add comment for future if somebody have same problem.. polylang from version 1.8 will add options to add flag from plugin settings page, right now you can get this version from link https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/developers/ just download "Development Version (svn)" but only if stable version 1.8 its not released